# How to suppress output from info() in Python scripts called by reticulate in R?

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am using the `reticulate` package to call a Python script from R. The script is being called many times so I would like to suppress output to the console each time it is called. The script I am calling is part of a Python module. It imports the `logging` module and prints messages using the `info()` function. I was wondering if there is a way to suppress that output from printing onto the R console, *without having to modify the underlying Python script.* I have tried both `py_capture_output()` and `py_suppress_warnings()` but neither of those will prevent the output from being printed.